# Como formatar um Double trocando o ponto por vírgula e mantendo 2 casas decimais em VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, formatação

Preciso transformar o resultado de um valor de `As Double` para o padrão numérico brasileiro que usa vírgula ao invés de ponto (e também manter somente 2 casas decimais), Assim:

```
' variaveis de teste                       ' valores esperados de saida   
Dim t1 as double = 123                     ' ~> 123,00
Dim t2 as double = 123.123                 ' ~> 123,12
Dim t3 as double = 123123132112321321.123  ' ~> 123123132112321321,12
Dim t4 as double = 0.123                   ' ~> 0,12
Dim t4 as double = 0.158123                ' ~> 0,16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `ToString` tem uma sobrecarga que aceita um `CultureInfo` como parâmetro. Passe este parâmetro usando a cultura que desejas.

```
Dim valor = 5.89d
valor.ToString(new CultureInfo("pt-br"))
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ayIqvm)</sup>

Comment: Isso mesmo! Muito obrigado! Já estava pensando em umas coisas doidas do tipo `ToString().Replace()` rs

Answer (score 2):

Um valor `Double` é só um número, ele não possui formatação, só é possível transformá-lo em `String` aplicando uma formatação. Esta formatação deve usar uma cultura, no caso a brasileira.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization
                
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim ptbr = new CultureInfo("pt-br")
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", 123.ToString("N2", ptbr))
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", 123.123.ToString("N2", ptbr))
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", 123123132112321321.123d.ToString("N2", ptbr))
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", 0.123.ToString("N2", ptbr))
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", 0.158123.ToString("N2", ptbr))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uio3h9). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1FIx1J). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/FormatNumber.vb).

Só note que se isto for [dinheiro o `Double` não é o tipo adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Comment: sim o @LINQ acabou passando a resposta acima, e da forma que ele colocou ficou mais simples, mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: Embora não faça exatamente o que você pediu

Comment: na verdade faz sim, o que preciso é só trocar o ponto por virgula e não formatar como dinheiro ou moeda =D

Comment: Então sua pergunta foi mal formulada porque ela mostra claramente que precisa ter apenas 2 casas decimais em todos os casos.

Comment: alterei a pergunta para ficar mais clara então

Comment: Portanto a minha está correta conforme a sua pergunta, e a do LINQ, apesar da boa intenção, não: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qy7Ids